# How can I make a HTML page mobile friendly?

Tags: html, mobile

I work for a non-profit ministry. We have a website made up of thousands of HTML pages, some of which have been around since 1996. I can write basic HTML at best. Is there a website or tool I can use to convert our thousands of pages of HTML to a mobile friendly layout? My boss does not want to upgrade to Wordpress because it will take a lot of work to convert and we have limited resources. You can find our website [here](http://www.tldm.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try bootstrap or use jquery mobile

http://getbootstrap.com/

https://jquerymobile.com/